# Unreliable data entering in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

For our game we store one row per player & level on completion, we do it as the following:

```
    pl = PlayerLevel.all().filter('player_id =', player_id).filter('level_id =', level_id ).get()

    if not pl:
      pl = PlayerLevel()
      pl.level_id = level_id
      pl.player_id = player_id
      ...

    ...else update stuff..

    pl.put()
```

But for some reason this code has created two rows with the same player_id & level_id. The thing is we've seen this before as well.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of eventual consistency, which is [fully documented](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Ancestor_queries) throughout the App Engine docs. You *cannot* rely on queries - such as your `filter` call - to return up-to-date data if the query has no ancestor.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't noticed that! Explains a lot.